# How often/reliably can an MDM push out new or updated configuration profiles?

Tags: mobile-device-management, configuration-profiles

I am working on an idea that requires changing MDM-managed iOS device settings within a minute every few minutes.

Are there any OS limits to the frequency/reliability of APNS-initiated configuration profile updates?

Let's assume that we have a custom-built MDM that is supervising a single iOS device running iOS 9.3.3 and they have a 100% reliable network connection between them with unlimited bandwidth.

I'm interested to know if iOS enforces any limit to the frequency of updates that it will apply from the MDM.  Not been able to find this in any docs.

Comment: Your question omits some important information that would help generate useful answers: how many devices; what kinds of devices; MDM server brand/software; bandwidth and reliability of network infrastructure, etc. This is too broad a question to garner any realistic responses.

Comment: @IconDaemon Added detail to question for focus.